# Questions with no acceptable answer

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

I asked a question on SO some time ago and none of the answers were appropriate.

The question is effectively dead, but it affects my 'accept' rate negatively.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you explained why none of the answers are appropriate? (Both in comments to those answers, and by editing the question itself.)

Comment: If you're still interested in the question, you may want to see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: @Peter: Yes, both.

Comment: @Popular: I hadn't thought of 'bumping'. Not sure the question is worth a bounty, though.

Comment: yeah, it's not the most helpful page ever. Once in a while we get "I know this is a dupe of [other question] but the answers there don't help me:" with varying degrees of success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not accept an answer if you don't think any of the answers sufficiently answer the question.

I don't think there's a whole lot more to it than that.  The accept rate isn't all that important.

Comment: "...isn't all that important": I guess you're right, even though (for me) it feels awkward.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this is a *valid* solution, but...

Since you can always undo the "correct" answer and select a different one, maybe you could post a CW answer saying "There is currently no suitable answer to my question" and accept that, and then if a real answer comes along you can undo and re-accept that.

This means your 'accept rate' isn't penalised for a failure to find a solution, but unfortunately has the side effect of making your question *look* answered, and thus may not attract so many people trying to solve it.

Comment: Heh, well it seems two people don't like this answer, but haven't said *why* they don't like it?